# Disable Fullpage JS on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am initializing Fullpage.js on a button click like so:

```
$('.fullpage-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'left',
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
});
```

I am trying to build a button that when clicked disables Fullpage.js, essentially toggling it on and off. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you destroy it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try destroying and recreating it

```
$('.fullpage-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    if($('#fullpage').hasClass('fp-destroyed')){            
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'left',
            scrollOverflow: true
        });
     } else {
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
     }
});
```

Comment: So easy thank you @karthick, and thanks as always @Alvaro! I'm starting to really love this plugin :)